# Passing a variable content to a modal dialog

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have a iFrame with a embedded Youtube video on it. When the user click in a button while the video is playing I want to open a modal window where the user can enter some note related to the video position.
I have checked [popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup), [popup_forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_forms), and [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools). **ctools** appear to be the most useful to me.

I want to open modal dialog from my button (not the generated **ctools** link), and I need to pass a variable to my form from my jquery button.  Is it possible?